# Browsing web page stored on local machine

Tags: ios, network

I am developing a web site and would like to check how it looks on my iPad and iPhone. Is there a way I can set up my mac and devices so that I can develop the web site locally, but view it on my devices over the local wifi?

I'm looking to replicate the functionality whereby you can just save an HTML file in your text editor and press refresh in the browser and the page updates, except that the browser in question will be on my iPhone.

I'm running Lion and everything is connected to the same network, which uses a time capsule as a base station. I know very little about networking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable the web server on your Mac via System Preferences:
[image]

You can then save the file in your Personal Website folder, as described in System Preferences. Use the supplied URL on both your Mac and on your iOS devices. The System Preferences panel will walk you through it fairly well.

Comment: Fantastic. I had no idea it would be that easy!